# Is there a way to create nested mat-select inside mat-option in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select

I'm developing filters for some datasets and one of the filters I need must also have a subfilter. In particular, I want the user to be able to choose one or multiple kind of plants (main filter) and for each one, to also be able to decide if it will be healthy or not (subfilter).

So far my HTML looks like this:

```
<p>Filter by:</p>
<form class="filters-form" [formGroup]="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <mat-form-field class="filter-field">
    <mat-label>Plants </mat-label>
            
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="droplist" formControlName='cropsFilter' 
                matNativeControl multiple>
      <div *ngFor="let cropOption of cropOptions; index as i">
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onCropsFilterChange($event)" [value]="cropOption"> 
                    {{cropOption}}</mat-option>
        <div *ngIf="checkSubfilterExistance(cropOption)" [formGroupName]='formOptions[i]'>
          <mat-form-field class='subfilter' *ngIf="hasPlantSubFilter">
            <mat-label>Presence of disease </mat-label>
            <mat-select disableOptionCentering  [value]="diseasePresenceFilter[i]" 
                        formControlName='diseasePresenceFilter' matNativeControl
                        (selectionChange)="onDiseasePresenceFilterChange($event,cropOption)"> 
              <mat-option value="Y">Yes</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="N">No</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <!--  More filters -->
<form>
```

The two functions I use in my ts file onCropsFilterChange and onDiseasePresenceFilterChange are the following

```
onCropsFilterChange(event: MatOptionSelectionChange) {
    
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      console.log("Inside onCropsFilterChange")
      console.log("This cropsArray")
      console.dir(this.cropsArray)
      console.log("This form value")
      console.dir(this.form.value)
      //this.cropsFilter = this.form.value.cropsFilter;
      let forDeletion= ['Y','N'];
      if(this.form.value.cropsFilter && this.form.value.cropsFilter.length>0){
        let cropFormString = event.source.value.split("|")[0];
          cropFormString  = 'form'+cropFormString.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("");
          let cropIndex = this.cropOptions.indexOf(event.source.value);
        if(this.form.value.cropsFilter.includes(event.source.value)){
          this.form.value.cropsFilter = this.form.value.cropsFilter.filter(item => item !== event.source.value);
          this.form.controls[cropFormString].value.diseasePresenceFilter = null;
        }else{
          this.form.value.cropsFilter.push(event.source.value);
        };
        this.diseasePresenceFilter[cropIndex] = this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter;
        this.form.value.cropsFilter = this.form.value.cropsFilter.filter(item => !forDeletion.includes(item));
        this.cropsFilter = this.form.value.cropsFilter;
      }else if(this.form.value.cropsFilter==null || this.form.value.cropsFilter.length==0){
        this.cropsFilter = [event.source.value];
        this.form.value.cropsFilter = [event.source.value]; 
      }
      
      console.log("This crpopsFilter:")
      console.dir(this.cropsFilter);
      console.log("This form value")
      console.dir(this.form.value);  
    }
  }

onDiseasePresenceFilterChange(event: MatSelectChange, crop: string) {
    console.log('Inside onDiseasePresenceFilterChange');
    console.dir(event)
    console.log("This form value")
    console.dir(this.form.value);
    if (event && event.value) {
      
      let cropIndex = this.cropOptions.indexOf(crop);
      console.log("Inside if, cropIndex")
      console.dir(cropIndex);
      //if(cropIndex != -1 && this.diseasePresenceFilter[cropIndex] != event.value){
        console.log("this.diseasePresenceFilter");
        console.dir(this.diseasePresenceFilter)
        console.log("crop");
        console.dir(crop)
        let cropFormString = crop.split("|")[0];
        cropFormString  = 'form'+cropFormString.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("");
        console.log("this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter");
        console.dir(this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter);
        //this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter = event.value;
        this.diseasePresenceFilter[cropIndex] = this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter;
        //this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter = this.form.get(cropFormString).value.diseasePresenceFilter;
        
      //}

      console.log('this.form')
      console.dir(this.form)
      this.currentPage = 1;
      this.paginate();
      this.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

But it's not working correctly most of the time. The only way for it to work properly is to *always pick all the plants first and then the presence of disease or if the plants have the same option selected in the presence of disease subfilter*. If for example I pick a plant and set its presence of disease to 'Y' and then pick another plant and set its presence of disease to 'N' the moment that I pick a third plant (before even setting a value for its presence of disease subfilter) the subfilters of the previous plants get all mixed up and some even become undefined.
It seems like the onDiseasePresenceFilterChange function is called even without selecting anything on that mat-select.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Comment: **not** use in the same tag `formControlName` and `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @Eliseo you are right that code was outdated, I have changed [(ngModel)] to [value] but still have the same issues.